# iPhone 5 Keyboard sizing

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, ios6

I've been testing my app in the 4-inch and 3.5-inch iPhone simulators, and when bringing up a keyboard with a UITextField in the 4-inch simulator in landscape mode, it's squished up to the side. It looks like a normal 3.5-inch keyboard:

[image]

Am I missing something telling it to stretch properly?

Please note - I don't have access to an actual iPhone 5 device to test on. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note: rotating to portrait and back again to landscape resulted in the same thing. Portrait orientation is normal.

Comment: Weird. Are you sure you're running the simulator with iOS6 (maybe your simulator is set to the 4 inch model but running iOS5?)

Comment: Bingo. That's it - iOS 5.1 + 4 inch screen. Thanks.

Comment: Happened with me also :iOS 5.1 + 4 inch screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your simulator is set to the 4-inch model but is running iOS5--this setup is possible in iOS Simulator but doesn't exist in the wild.

Comment: I'm relieved its not something that could get out into a shipping version! Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know what you mean, had a few panic moments too when testing things in iOS Simulator! :)